# How to fix syntax error, unexpected T_IF error in php?

Tags: php, syntax

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in view.php on line 27

I really dont see any problem in my code, why this is happening, please help. Im a beginner in PHP

Where my LINE 21 is >>  **if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))**

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY id"))
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $total_result = $result->num_rows;
        $total_pages = ceil($total_result / $per_page)

        if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
            $show_page = $_GET['page'];

            if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
            {
                $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
                $end = $start + $per_page;
            }
            else
            {
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page;
            }               

        }
        else
        {
            $start = 0;
            $end = $per_page;
        }


        //display paginations
        echo "<p> View pages: ";
        for ($i=1; $i < $total_pages; $i++)
        { 
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
            {
                echo  $i . " ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a href='view-pag.php?$i'>" . $i . "</a> | ";
            }

        }
        echo "</p>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "No result to display.";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Check your semicolons before that line.

Comment: lol, why is this question `closed as too localized`, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why is it closed as "too localized" ? It's not the case in anyway! Getting this error is the classic pitfall when PHP beginners and forgot a `;`  on previous line. It is not specific to this code! Please consider to reopen it, or close it for another reason, but not this one!

Comment: It's a good question. Not "too localized" Helped me with this error but another cause for it.

Comment: It is just plain untrue that "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

Answer (score 154, accepted):

PHP parser errors take some getting used to; if it complains about an unexpected 'something' at line X, look at line X-1 first. In this case it will not tell you that you forgot a semi-colon at the end of the previous line , instead it will complain about the `if` that comes next.

You'll get used to it :)

Comment: Thanks, saw my silly misstake. I missed semicol on prev line 20. damm how dumb me :/

Comment: @STEEL don't beat yourself up over it ;-) understanding php errors sometimes takes some imagination

Comment: I wish to do well in PHP. Thanks

Comment: Thank you... my `line x - 1` was `eles if (gettype($res) == 'boolean')` !!!

Comment: Jack, you are a genius !

Comment: I'd also suggest that if you have copied your code from somewhere and pasted it into a html document that there might be some hidden characters.  I just ran into this problem and it was because of this very issue.

Comment: You also get this error if you accidentally damage your previous function signarure: `function () { /* long function body */ } if (true) ;` That happened to me just now. I deleted the function name and the error line was waaaay down the script file.

Comment: Most simplest solution I can get for this error...Thanks a ton @Ja͢ck

Comment: *look at line X-1 first* That's the best PHP advice I've ever read!

Comment: This Worked Perfectly I forgot to use simcolon at the end of previos line

Answer (score 5):

add semi-colon the line before:

```
$total_pages = ceil($total_result / $per_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue

```
  $total_result = $result->num_rows;
```

try this

```
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY id"))
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $total_result = $result->num_rows;
        $total_pages = ceil($total_result / $per_page);

        if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
        {
            $show_page = $_GET['page'];

            if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
            {
                $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
                $end = $start + $per_page;
            }
            else
            {
                $start = 0;
                $end = $per_page;
            }               

        }
        else
        {
            $start = 0;
            $end = $per_page;
        }


        //display paginations
        echo "<p> View pages: ";
        for ($i=1; $i < $total_pages; $i++)
        { 
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
            {
                echo  $i . " ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a href='view-pag.php?$i'>" . $i . "</a> | ";
            }

        }
        echo "</p>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "No result to display.";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}


?>
```