# PHP form verification

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP so please be gentle!

I'm trying to build a simple PHP form validation with an error message/confirm message. When I submit the form, it's supposed to check if fields are empty and display the corresponding message. But it keeps giving me an error and I have no idea why:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in process.php on line 6

Here's `process.php` code:

```php
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
//If form was submitted
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
    $errormsg = ""; //Initialize errors
    if ($_POST[fname]){
        $fname = $_POST[fname]; //If fname was entered
    }
    else{
        $errormsg = "Please enter first name";
    }
    if ($_POST[lname]){
        $lname = $_POST[lname]; //If lname was entered
    }
    else{
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error
            $errormsg = $errormsg . ", last name";
        }
        else{
             $errormsg = "Please enter last name";
        }    
    }
    if ($_POST[email]){
        $email = $_POST[email]; //If email was entered
    }
    else{
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error
            $errormsg = $errormsg . " & email";
        }else{
            $errormsg = "Please enter email";
        }
    }   
}
if ($errormsg){ //If any errors display them
    echo "<div class=\"box red\">$errormsg</div>";
}
//If all fields present
if ($fname && $lname && $email){
    //Do something
    echo "<div class=\"box green\">Form completed!</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you pointed out line 6, because line 6 in the above is just some html. Plus, you have a NUMBEr of unquoted keys , e.g. `$_POST[lname]`. php will politely treat them as quoted keys, but will issue warnings.

Comment: if ($_POST[fname]){
 is line 6. And Thanks for the heads up on the quotes

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit'])`!!!

Comment: any other code you're not showing that would be before the bad if() statement? "Unexpected" usually means you'r emissing a `;` or something in earlier code, but your if() is the first bit of actual PHP code in the snippet you've shown.

Comment: That's the only PHP on the process page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your $_POST variables were missing single quotation marks, which is probably what caused the errors. However, generally speaking, there are other code suggestions which I've layed out.
I restructured your code to be more scalable and follow better practice with the following enhancements:

1. Form values will remember their previous value and not erased on each post.
2. Removed the 'submitted' field and replaced with `if (!empty($_POST)) {}` to make sure form was posted.
3. Moved error messages into an array. This is more maintainable and readable to my taste (imagine having 15+ fields to test for).
4. Added validate() function to run on your validation tests.
5. Removed variable assignments ($fname = $_POST['fname']) since they were not used except for the validation, which can access them directly.
6. Moved all tests inside the main if statement.

Hope this helps!

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : ''?>"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : ''?>"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''?>"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
//If form was submitted

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST['fname'])){
       $errors[] = 'First name must be entered.';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['lname'])){
        $errors[] = 'Last name must be entered.';
    }

    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
       $errors[] = 'Email address must be entered.';
    }


    if ($errors){ //If any errors display them
        $error_msg = implode('<br>',$errors);
        echo "<div class=\"box red\">$error_msg</div>";
    } 
    //If all fields present
    elseif (validate()){
        //Do something
        echo "<div class=\"box green\">Form completed and validated!</div>";
    }
}

function validate() {
    /*you can run all your validation methods here, such as check for length, regexp email verification, etc.*/
    $validated = false;
    if ($_POST['fname'] && $_POST['lname'] && $_POST['email']) { 
        $validated = true;
    }
    return $validated;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `"` on post array that is the reason for your error `$_POST[lname]` change to `$_POST['lname'];` . Pass string to your `$_POST[];`

```
if ($_POST["fname"]){
        $fname = $_POST[fname]; //If fname was entered
    }
    else{
        $errormsg = "Please enter first name";
    }
    if ($_POST["lname"]){
        $lname = $_POST[lname]; //If lname was entered
    }
    else{
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error
            $errormsg = $errormsg . ", last name";
            }
        else{
             $errormsg = "Please enter last name";
        }    
    }
    if ($_POST["email"]){
        $email = $_POST["email"]; //If email was entered
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the $_POST variables use syntax as $_POST['your variable name']

I corrected your code as below:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
//If form was submitted

if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {
$errormsg = ""; //Initialize errors
    if ($_POST['fname']){
        $fname = $_POST['fname']; //If fname was entered
    }
    else{
        $errormsg = "Please enter first name";
    }
    if ($_POST['lname']){
        $lname = $_POST['lname']; //If lname was entered
    }
    else{
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error
            $errormsg = $errormsg . ", last name";
            }
        else{
             $errormsg = "Please enter last name";
        }    
    }
    if ($_POST['email']){
        $email = $_POST['email']; //If email was entered
    }
    else{
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error
            $errormsg = $errormsg . " & email";
        }else{
            $errormsg = "Please enter email";
        }
    }   
}
if ($errormsg){ //If any errors display them
    echo "<div class=\"box red\">$errormsg</div>";
}
//If all fields present
if ($fname && $lname && $email){
    //Do something
    echo "<div class=\"box green\">Form completed!</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is a lack of `register globals` being enabled (which is a good thing in my eyes) and not using proper string encapsulation.

You need to change every existence of `$_POST[word]` to `$_POST['word']`. Note the `'`.

Comment: I added the quotes, and now my page is telling me "no data received"

Comment: @Ktown hard to believe if you are having the php code on `process.php` page as ur `action` is `action="process.php"`

Comment: Now it's giving me the same error as before. Which is 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code on line 6
    if ($_POST['fname']){

Answer (score 0):

As Ohgodwhy said,

You need to change every existence of `$_POST[word]` to `$_POST['word']`. Note the `'`.

And why are you using `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">`, this is not a good practice. Better use.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
```

Comment: i dont think the one you mentioned above is needed at all just <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> will do the job ,the user just want to check whether the submit button is pressed or not.no need to add extra line of codes.and $_POST[word] is not a good practice but it will work,it wont throw any error.

Comment: So why is it giving me this error then?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code on line 6
    if ($_POST['fname']){

Comment: @Ktown can you point out the line in your question which is giving you the error?

Comment: if ($_POST['fname']){

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860371/syntax-error-unexpected-t-if)

Answer (score -1):

I am Using thing type of simple validation. Here is my javascript code:

```
var ck_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,50}$/;
var ck_email = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/;
var ck_mob = /^[0-9 ]{8,11}$/;

function validate(form){
var name = form.name.value;
var email = form.email.value;
var mob = form.mob.value;

var errors = [];
if (!ck_name.test(name)) 
{
errors[errors.length] = "Your valid Name .";
}
if (!ck_email.test(email)) 
{
errors[errors.length] = "Your must enter a valid email address.";
}
if (!ck_mob.test(mob)) 
{
errors[errors.length] = "Your valid Mobile Number.";
}

if (errors.length > 0) 
{
reportErrors(errors);
return false;
}
return true;
}

function reportErrors(errors)
{
var msg = "Please Enter Valide Data...\n";
for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) 
{
var numError = i + 1;
msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
}
alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: this is straight javascript. I'm looking for server side validation, not client side. Thanks for the response though